# Which one of the option/s is/are correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p,q$ be primes and $n \in \Bbb N,$ such that $p \nmid\ n-1.$ If $p\  |\ n^q-1$ then which one of the following option/s is/are correct?
>
> $(1)$ $p\ |\ q-1.$
>
> $(2)$ $q\ |\ p-1.$
>
> $(3)$ $p\ |\ (p-1)(q-1).$
>
> $(4)$ $q\ |\ (q-1)(p-1).$

**My attempt** $:$ If I take $p=3, q=2$ and $n=2$  then I find that the given condition holds but option $(1)$ and hence option $(3)$ fails to hold. What about options $(2)$ and $(4)$? It is quite clear that either both the options $(2)$ and $(4)$ are correct or both the options are false. How to prove or disprove $(2)$? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: What have you edited @janmarqz?

Comment: Changed the | to \mid in the first line.  It makes the slash look nicer

Comment: better latex for $p$ divides not  $n-1$

Comment: Dub Dub dubuque @Bill Dubuque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ divides $n^{q} - 1$ then $n^{q}\equiv 1$ ($\mathrm{mod}$ $p$). So the order of $n$ modulo $p$ divides $q$. Hence the order is $1$ or $q$, and yet $p$ does not divide $n -1$ so the order is $q$.

Now apply Euler's theorem and once more use the fact that if $n^{k} \equiv 1$ ($\mathrm{mod}$ $p$) then the order of $n$ modulo $p$ divides $k$.